# How can I measure, then optimize, database access

Tags: ms-access

I have been told that "we have a feeling that the database is too slow" and that I should sort it out. Not being a database guru, I am looking for ideas.

My idea is to measure existing performance and then to attempt optimizations, measuring the effect of each.

Can anyone suggest a good (preferably FOSS) tool for measuring access to an MS Access database?

And a good book or site (or just make some suggestions) for a general approach to optimizing an MS Access database?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update: it seems that database writes, which are all INSERT, never UPDATE, are the problem. There are very few queries (it seems like data is stored "just in case")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also look at the built-in performance analyzer wizard.  From the Access 2003 main menu, Tools-> Analyze -> Performance.  If you have Access 2007, look on the Database Tools ribbon.

However, I think your first order of business should be to get a handle on "*we have a feeling that the database is too slow*".  Find out which aspects of the application are too slow and focus your optimization efforts on those.  Don't waste time optimizing parts which don't need it.

Comment: +1 thanks. I will ask some questions, but will probably profile everything.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, get a baseline measurement, tweak and then measure again. I made a quick routine that runs a query X times (normally 20 or so) and averages out the response time. That way I can see if I am making an improvement.

Before you start make sure that you have compacted the access database as this often helps to speed things up. After that I would look at indexes and what queries are being run. A common mistake is to bind a form to a whole table, it works fine when the app is small but once you have lots of records it can drag.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to decompile if you have not done so already. If there are lots of subforms on tabs, there is no need to load the recordsource until the form is needed. With a little effort, you can usually reduce the subforms to one or two and just load forms into the subform control, as required. Oddly enough, a long path to the back-end  is detrimental to performance, so if you have one, consider a mapped drive.

As for tools, this may help:
[Microsoft's Unsupported Jet Optimization Tools and more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188211%28office.10%29.aspx)

You may also be interested in:
[Tony Toews on performance issues](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm)
[Query optimization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209126)

Answer (score 1):

Google Jet SHOWPLAN. It will tell you a lot about how Jet/ACE is optimizing your SQL statement.